# DB normalization - "OR" type of relation between tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I'm trying to normalize some old DB and I ended up with next tables:

**Shop**

```
id_shop
...
```

**API_type_one_credentials**

```
id_api_type_creds
fieldA
fieldB
```

**API_type_two_credentials**

```
id_api_type_creds
fieldC
fieldD
fieldE
```

Shop may have only one type of API, relate to only one set of credentials.

The only solution that pop ups in my mind is create one more table that would connect all the entities together:

**Shop_API_type**

```
id_shop
id_creds_api_type_one // TRUE
id_creds_api_type_two // NULL
...
```

But it looks wrong and feels like I'm missing something.

Is there another vector of the solution I should think about?

Comment: What if there's a type 3?

Comment: Rearranging designs to record supertypes/subtypes isn't either of the 2 things meant by "database normalization". (Namely, to a "1NF" & to higher NFs.) Why do you think this post is about database normalization? (Rhetorical.) PS Making such designs is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. [ask]

Comment: @Strawberry that's exact reason why I posted this question.

Comment: @philipxy thank you!!! Gods.. that's what I needed to clarify all my issues, thank you, man!
If you'd like to post it as an answer - I'll accept it as the best.

Comment: Just click on marking it a duplicate. Often-asked duplicates should be closed, not answered. [help] [meta] [meta.se] (Also this post doesn't seem to contain a clear statement of the problem/goal that  would allow someone to find it & an answer. It gives an example but doesn't clearly state a problem/goal/question.) PS Clarify via edits, not comments.